# How to get the value of a map from a key which is a POJO

Tags: dictionary, equals, key-value, hashcode, pojo

I got the following function

```
Map<MyClass, String> someFunction() {
    Map<MyClass, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    return result.put(new MyClass("someString"), "someOtherString"));
}
```

The implementation of MyClass looks like the following:

```
public class MyClass{

    String string;

    public MyClass(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((string== null) ? 0 : string.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
        if (string== null) {
            if (other.string!= null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!string.equals(other.string)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

In my test I am doing the following:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Map<MyClass, String> outcome = classUnderTest.someFunction();

    assertThat(outcome.get(new MyClass("someString")), is("someOtherString"));
}
```

But this test fails, because actual is null.
If I try the following:

```
assertThat(outcome.keySet(), hasItem(MY_CLASS));
```

this also fails, telling me, that these are different intantiations. I even tried to debug my test, but it never reaches the equals method. Can you tell me what is happening here?

Comment: what version of junit are you using?

Comment: Currently I am using version 4.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, that your method doesn't modify the objecT? I think, that `someFunction` replaces the `string` in `MyClass`. That causes that your object of `MyClass` return another hashCode.

A `HashMap` works like that:

put:

- compute `hashCode` of the key. Store value under that hashCode

get:

- compute `hashCode` of the key. Search for a value with that hashCode. If there is a value, then maybe call `equals`.

So: never use mutable values as key! Otherwise, you may lose your data (or make it difficult to resolve)

Just try to execute this test, it should be green

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest {

    Map<MyClass, String> someFunction() {
        Map<MyClass, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put(new MyClass("someString"), "someOtherString");
        return result;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Map<MyClass, String> outcome = someFunction();

        assertThat(outcome.get(new MyClass("someString")), is("someOtherString"));
    }

    public static class MyClass {

        String string;

        public MyClass(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

        public void setString(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((string == null) ? 0 : string.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
            if (string == null) {
                if (other.string != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!string.equals(other.string)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

but if you modify `MyClass` object after it was added to `Map`, the test became red:

```
Map<MyClass, String> someFunction() {
    Map<MyClass, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    MyClass key = new MyClass("someOldString");
    result.put(key, "someOtherString");
    key.setString("someString");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Actually I have no idea where that question came from. It's been too long and I even don't know the context anymore. I guess your answer strikes home, so I mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your function you are returning `null`

From the JavaDoc for HashMap:

> public V put(K key, V value)

```
Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

Specified by:
    put in interface Map<K,V>
Overrides:
    put in class AbstractMap<K,V>
Parameters:
    key - key with which the specified value is to be associated
    value - value to be associated with the specified key
Returns:
    the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)
```

put() returns what used to be there, not what you just put there